# How to build fetch URLadresse using twoo parameters inside?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sent request to Google Books using fetch to find book either by author or by tittle of book.

I don't have the problem to find books by using only one parameter where value is title of book for example:

```
   getData(value) {
    console.log(value);
    fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:${value}&printType=books&${myKey}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

But if I want to use as value either author or tittle of the boks url works wrong. Books are found anly by author:

```
getData(value) {
    console.log(value);
    fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:${value}&?q=intitle:${value}&printType=books&${myKey}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

How to built url to fing the bokks either by author or by tittle.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want either to search for the author or title, wouldn't be easier if you do a small condition before and use the respective URL?

```js
getValue(value, type){
   switch(type){
      case "title":
        fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:${value}&printType=books&${myKey}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        break;
      case "author":
        fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:${value}&printType=books&${myKey}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        break;
   }
}
```

`type` would be what you want to search (in this case "author" or "title").

Comment: Hi Francisco, thanks. I expanded the function by adding type, where I will have possibility to choose what exactly I am looking for, That's more handy and reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `|` (`OR`) between conditions, here you go:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:${value}|inauthor:${value}&printType=books&${myKey}`
```

My example query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers+intitle:david|inauthor:keyes
```